# TextClock not changing to 24hour format

Tags: kotlin, widget

I have a TextClock in a widget, and have set the format I would like for both 12hour and 24hour format. The problem is the TextClock does not display 24hour time when I change my phone to 24 hour time setting.

I have tried removing both format12Hour and format24Hour lines from my layout and it changes nothing.

How do I show 12 or 24 hour time on the widget depending on the phone setting?

My widget layout file:

```
<TextClock
            android:id="@+id/lw02_clock"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_50ssp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:format12Hour="hh:mm"
            android:format24Hour="HH:mm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the format12Hour, you should put "K:mm a".

As for the meaning of the letters, here's the list of the symbols and what they mean: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter

Comment: Thankyou! It works. Thats incredibly counter-intuitive to change the 12 hour formatting to get the 24 hour mode to work.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I agree, it shoudn't be such a pain...well, let's just focus on the fact that there're always solutions.
I wish you the best for the rest of your project!

Comment: I spoke a little too soon. This mostly works, but if I have the phone set to 12 hour mode, then when the time is between 12 and 12.59 - am or pm - it shows 0.00 to 0.59. I would like it to show 12.00 to 12.59 (and I don't want or need the am/pm indicator). My two lines are: android:format12Hour="k:mm".   android:format24Hour="HH:mm"

Comment: Okay - finally figured it out I think! It should be: android:format12Hour="h:mm"
            android:format24Hour="kk:mm"

Comment: So does it works properly, now?

Comment: Yes, I had a dumb moment, but finally figured it out. Thanks again, I've accepted your answer.